# IronRuby and Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, ironruby

When running Cucumber 0.5.1 with IronRuby 1.0 RC1, I get the following error:

```
IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `ScanAnchor': while scanning an alias: expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found
something else... (IronRuby::StandardLibrary::Yaml::ScannerException)
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `FetchAlias'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `FetchMoreTokens'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `PeekToken'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `Produce'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `ParseStreamNext'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `ComposeNode'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `ComposeNode'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `ComposeNode'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `ComposeDocument'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `GetNode'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `GetData'
        from IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml:0:in `MoveNext'
        from :0:in `load_file'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.5.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/platform.rb:10
        from C:/Program Files/IronRuby 0.9.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.5.1/bin/../lib/cucumber.rb:5
        from :0:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files/IronRuby 0.9.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.5.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:2
        from C:/Program Files/IronRuby 0.9.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from :0:in `require'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.5.1/bin/cucumber:5
        from c:/ruby/bin/cucumber:19
        from :0:in `require'
        from :0:in `load'
```

I have no idea what to do now.
I am trying to run the example cucumber features.

cucumber features (runs fine)
icucumber features (throws this error)

Comment: You might want to post that question on the IronRuby mailing list to get some more info. It might be a bug.
http://www.ruby-forum.com/forum/34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with the languages.yml file.
This file is being loaded in the platform.rb file on line 10, thats part of the cucumber gem.
What I tried:

1. Deleting the file, but that only
   resulted in a file not found error.
2. Leaving only English in the file.
   That did not work.
3. Clearing the file
   of all contents. Gave some nil
   method error.